# facebook Log In Button

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm implementing facebook authentication (register + login) at my website. Everything works fine, except for the button showing even if I'm logged in. Thanks in advance

```
    <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to my website</h1>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<span id="fb-login" class="hidden">
<fb:login-button registration-url="http://lemiart.com/register.php"></fb:login-button>
</span>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=306738122732711&xfbml=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: '306738122732711', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(){
    loggedIn();
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if (response.session){
    // user logged in. Let the auth.login subscription handle this
    } else {
        loggedOut();
    }
});

loggedIn = function() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    var welcome = document.getElementById('welcome');
    if (welcome) welcome.innerHTML += ' ' + response.id;
    document.getElementById('fb-login').className = "hidden";
    })
}

loggedOut = function() {
    document.getElementById('fb-login').className="";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation will always prompt the user to login. What you perhaps need to do is the following:

write a callback function to FB.init, which then checks if the user is logged into your application and then decide if you want to show the fb:login-button.

It would look something like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        //...
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            if (response.session){
              // user logged in. Let the auth.login subscription handle this
        } else {
            loggedOut();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you, but the fb-login button is set as hidden from the beggining. I don't understand why it is showing.

Comment: @vitor-subs The reason I structured it this way is to avoid the possibility of FB.init completing after the browser has already executed your FB.getLoginStatus call. I have derived my code snippet from http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3548493/how-to-detect-when-facebooks-fb-init-is-complete